# Match some strange characters in a `\w` match

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match("/\w+/", $s, $matches);
```

I have the PHP code above. I use it to match words in a string. It works great, except in one case.

**Example:**

`'This is a word'` should match `{'This','is','a','word'}`

`'Bös Tüb'` should match `{'Bös','Tüb'}`

The first example works, but the second does not. Instead it returns `{'B','s','T','b'}`, it does not see the `ö` and `ü` as a word character.

**Question**

How to match the ö and ü and any other characters that are normally used in names (they can be strange, this is about German and Turkish names)? Should I add them all manually (`/[a-zA-Z and all others as unicode]/`)?

***EDIT***

As I ofcourse forgot to mention, there are a lot of `\n`, `\r` and `' '` characters in between the words. This is why I am using Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `u` modifier to deal with Unicode characters. And then decode the matches with `utf8_decode()`.

```
$s = 'Bös Tüb';
preg_match("/\w+/u", $s, $matches); // use the 'u' modifier
var_dump(utf8_decode($matches[0])); // outputs: Bös
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks! \u003A\u0029

Answer (score 0):

If you need to separate by space you can use php explode func like:

```
$some_string = 'test some words';
$words_arr = explode(' ', $some_string);
var_dump($words_arr);
```

No matter what are the chars into the string, the script will work.

EDIT:
You can try:

```
preg_match("/\w+/u", $s, $matches);
```

for unicode.

Comment: See my edit: There are a lot of other, non-word characters between the words. I am in a position where it is hard to filter them out.

Comment: Do you have numbers into the words?

Comment: No numbers. Just 'characters', the ones humans use to make a word, and in particular a name.

Comment: Ok, try then to define the unicode into the pattern ... like 
preg_match("/\w+/u", $s, $matches);